# What is the formula for calculating the median in Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: reporting, pentaho

Was looking around Pentaho Report Designer and noticed that there is no function available for calculating the **median** of a data set (i.e. over rows of data).  I"m able to order the data set and count the number of rows.  However, since there appears to be no means to get to the middle number (or middle 2 numbers if the total row count is even), I can't manually calculate this.  There appears to be no "index" (for lack of a better term) associated with each row of a record set that I could use to find the mid point.

Answer (score 0):

You can define functions in report designer which calculates the median on basis of number of rows and then use that function instead of the data column.